# Use regex to search for a specific word between an exact string and the first occurrence of another exact string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge text file (200k lines).
I use Notepad++ and I need it to return the lines where this word comes between a specific string ("string1") and the first occurrence of another (" "). For example, I am looking for the word "myword" and the text files look like this:

```
"string1" "string 2 with myword in it" "string 3 also with myword in it" "string 4 random stuff"
"string1" "string 2 random stuff" "string 3 also with myword in it" "string 4 random stuff"
"string1" "string 2 with myword in it" "string 3 random stuff" "string 4 random stuff"
```

The results of the search should return line 1 and 3, but not line 2.
So I thought it like this:

```
(?<="string1" ")(.*)(\bmyword\b)(.*)(?=")
```

But this also returns line 2, because myword is in string 3.

I am a noob when it comes to regex, this is my first time ever using it...

Please help easy my pain :)

Comment: Try `(?<="string1" ")((?:(?!"\h+").)*)\bmyword\b([^"]*)`

Comment: Gee, that seemed to work! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a solution that will include a pattern that matches up to the `"`+space+`"` - `(?:(?!" ").)*`:

```
(?<="string1" ")((?:(?!" ").)*?)\bmyword\b([^"]*)
```

**Details**:

- `(?<="string1" ")` - a positive lookbehind making sure there is `"string1" "` substring immediately to the left of the current location (can be replaced with `"string1" "\K`)
- `((?:(?!" ").)*?)` - a tempered greedy token matching any char other than newline that does not start `" "` sequence, as few as possible (Group 1)
- `\bmyword\b` - a whole word `myword`
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `"`.

[image]

Comment: That's great! Is there a way I can make Notepad++ highlight just "myword" and not the whole string between the 2 boundaries?

Comment: You may use `"string1" "(?:(?!" ").)*?\K\bmyword\b` and use it with *Mark* ->  *Mark All*.

Comment: I meant in the search results, Notepad++ highlights the entire string 2. I only want it to highlight "myword", it will help me visually (I get hundreds of results).

Comment: Once a word is highlighted, the same words are highlighted by default.

Comment: In your screenshot, in the find results, the whole string 2 is highlighted (red on yellow), not just myword. I need it to highlight just myword, like here: http://imgur.com/a/r59gr (but of course, using your regex). So I am asking about the find results, not the actual text file... It's not critical, so don't stress about it. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Oh, my bad. Yes, this works. The "mark" part confused me. 